# Getting file path from command line arguments in python

Tags: python, path, command-line-arguments, argparse

I would like to read a file path from command line arguments, using argparse. Is there any optimal way to check if the path is relative (file is in current directory) or the complete path is given? (Other than checking the input and adding current directory to file name if the path does not exist.)

Comment: You could use [`os.path.isabs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isabs).

Comment: This will work for me, Thanks @DisplayName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Display Name said, `os.path.isabs` along with `sys.argv` is probably the best:

```
import sys
import os

fpath = sys.argv[-1]

print(os.path.isabs(fpath))
print(fpath)
```

output

```
>>> 
True
C:\Users\310176421\Desktop\Python\print.py
>>>
```

some cmd stuff

```
C:\Users\310176421\Desktop\Python>python print.py C:\Users\310176421\Desktop\tes
t.txt
True
C:\Users\310176421\Desktop\test.txt

C:\Users\310176421\Desktop\Python>python print.py whatever
False
whatever
```

Comment: ``` 
>>> %Run aaa.py C:\Users\motamed\Desktop\mo3ta\summary
False
C:UsersmotamedDesktopmo3tasummary
```

Comment: What OS and python version are you using?